# How do you substitute into solutions in sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

Consider this simple MWE:

```
from sympy.solvers.diophantine import diophantine
from sympy import symbols
x, y, z = symbols("x, y, z", integer=True)
diophantine(x*(2*x + 3*y - z))
```

This outputs:

```
[(t_0, t_1, 2*t_0 + 3*t_1), (0, n1, n2)]
```

> If I want to create instances of these solutions I would like, for
> example, to able to substitute integer values into t_0 and t_1.  How
> can you do that?

I tried e.g.

```
diof = diophantine(x*(2*x + 3*y - z))
list(diof)[0][0].subs(t_0, 0)
```

but that gives

```
NameError: name 't_0' is not defined
```

Comment: FYI, `sympy.solvers.diophantine.diophantine` should be `sympy.solvers.diophantine`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t_0` is not defined as a *Python* variable. You can create the Python variable in a couple of different ways:

```py
from sympy import symbols
t_0 = symbols("t_0")
```

Alternatively, you can capture the symbol generated from your SymPy calculation into a Python variable. Here's one way:

```py
diofl = list(diof) # Assuming that diof is as you had defined it.

t_0 = diofl[1][0] # Presuming that this is the part of diofl
                  # that contains the correct symbol. Print 
                  # diofl[1][0] to be sure!
```

After that, you can then use `t_0` as an argument of the `subs()` method.

Comment: After calling subs, there isn't a NameError, but the result is still t_0, unevaluated. Is this normal? How can you evaluate it thereafter?

Comment: @DavidCian Notice that I wrote "Presuming that this is the part of diofl that contains the correct symbol. Print diofl[1][0] to be sure!". If `diofl[1][0]` isn't already the correct symbol, then you'll have to try a different part of `diofl`, say, `diofl[0][0]`.

Comment: I did, it is the correct symbol. I'm pretty sure it's a bug in the module, but for other people that come across this issue here is an easy workaround: convert the expression to a string, then sympify it, then everything works as expected.

Comment: @DavidCian For what it's worth, I couldn't reproduce your problem.